# Double right click mouse event in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, double-click, right-click

It it possible to catch a double **right** click event in Actionscript 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is with AIR.  You can't capture RIGHT_CLICK in regular AS3, unfortunately.

There is, however, always the possibility of capturing right click events in JavaScript, and using ExternalInterface to call an event handler in the Flash program.  See [this blog](http://www.uza.lt/2007/08/19/solved-right-click-in-as3/), for example.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can catch `RIGHT_CLICK` at the moment :

1. You need player >11.2
2. Add additional compiler options `-swf-version=19`
3. Use this code :

   `stage.doubleClickEnabled = true;`
   `stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK, handler);`

In handler you can save time of previous click, compare with second click and if it`s shorter than 0.5 seconds dispatch your own RIGHT_DOUBLE_CLICK event.